# Comment appelle-t-on ce maquillage blanc + rouge, d'avant la révolution ?

Tags: terminologie

Comment appelle-t-on ce genre de maquillage blanc + rouge, typique (ou stéréotypique) de la période avant la révolution française ?

Y a-t-il un terme exact ?
Sinon, quel expression permettrait de désigner au mieux ce maquillage ?

[image]
*(détail du film "Raid Dingue")*

Answer (score 3):

Je ne connais pas de terme spécifique autre que **[fard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fard)**.

Le blanc était généralement du blanc de céruse et le rouge, fait à partir de craie de Briançon ou de carmin (tiré de la cochenille, une petit insecte).

Source: [article décrivant le maquillage sous l'ancien régime](http://www.histoire-pour-tous.fr/histoire-de-france/4880-maquillage-et-cosmetiques-sous-lancien-regime.html).

Answer (score 2):

Comme «une manière de parler sarcastique», d’après l’édition de 1735 du *Dictionaire comique, satyrique, critique, burlesque, libre et proverbial* de Philibert-Joseph Le Roux, [via *GoogleBooks*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m8E-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA661&lpg=PA661&dq=%22Visage+de+pl%C3%A2tre.C%27est+une+mani%C3%A9re+de+parler+satyrique%22&source=bl&ots=VNsyE0Xkux&sig=DK35kmZnXwfOoTYsMZcO41RXfSI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJwNOCjO7XAhVDQt8KHS8WANgQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22Visage%20de%20pl%C3%A2tre.C'est%20une%20mani%C3%A9re%20de%20parler%20satyrique%22&f=false), l’expression «**Visage de plâtre**» peut servir pour dire:

«qu'on a coûtume de donner à Paris aux vieilles personnes, qui malgré leur âge se requinquent encore & **se plâtrent le visage de blanc & de rouge**, pour paroître jeunes; on l'applique aussi aux jeunes qui se fardent avec excès».

Dans  [l’entrée pour “poudre”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poudre) dans *CNRTL-TLFi*, il y a référence aussi à l’appellation «visage de plâtre» (sous l’item ‘c) COSMÉTOLOGIE’)  où on dirait que l’effet (au moins du blanc) n’était pas forcement voulu mais plutôt le résultat de la poudre qui tombait des perruques:

> En 1759 ou 1760... j'étais un «**visage de plâtre**» comme on surnommait
>   alors les jeunes officiers à cause de la poudre de nos perruques qui
>   nous inondait la figure et les épaules(ADAM, Enf. Aust.,1902, p. 349).

---

(Peut-être à voir aussi dans cette entrée, «poudre [de riz]» et les adjectifs [sous REM. 1.] «Poudrederisé, poudrederizé, -ée» et «Poudrerisé, poudrerizé, -ée»)

Answer (score 1):

En complément à la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28309) où on mentionne le *fard*, en ce qui a trait à l'emploi de la couleur rouge et de la « matière, colorant, pigment fournissant une couleur rouge » (Larousse en ligne, [*se mettre du rouge à joues*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rouge/70010?q=rouge#69247)) bien on a *le rouge*, c'est-à-dire l'emploi par métonymie de l'adjectif substantivé avec les emplois *mettre du, son rouge; rouge à joues* (TLFi) :

> C'était un de ces esprits que leur fierté met dans la position d'une
>   jeune femme qui arrive sans rouge dans un salon où l'usage du rouge
>   est général.
>
> [ Stendhal, *Armance*, 1827, p. 28, au TLFi à [*rouge*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouge) III. A 1 b β ]
>
> Sa rivale comptait voir une femme pâle, languissante ; la marquise
>   avait mis du rouge, et se présenta dans tout l’éclat d’une parure qui
>   rehaussait encore sa beauté.
>
> [ Honoré de Balzac, *La Femme de trente ans*, Paris, 1832 au Wiktionnaire à [*rouge*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouge#Nom_commun) (nom com.) ]

*Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*) mentionne comme emplois métonymiques avec la couleur, 1636 pour la *matière qui fournit un colorant rouge* et, pour le *fard* : 1560 pour *rouge d'Espagne*, et 1690 pour *rouge* comme dans *mettre du rouge* à l'origine de l'emploi spécialisé *rouge à lèvres*.